# How can I add a custom menu item to an existing Wordpress menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to add a home icon as the first menu item in my Wordpress menu. How can I do it?
TO let you know, this code didn't work:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
    if (is_single() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li>Show whatever</li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

I have this in functions.php:

```
add_theme_support('nav-menus');
if ( function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
register_nav_menus(
array(
'main' => 'Main Nav'
)
);
}
```

and this is how I fire the menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'main', 'container' => 'nav' )); ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the  `if (is_single() && $args->theme_location == 'primary')` condition that is preventing the first code block from working?

Comment: I don't know, I edited the primary to main of course, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to add filters and hooks for this.

You can edit your navigation in your theme files, usually it's in the header.php file. Add a new list item with your icon or text and put the link for it. Plain HTML.

Comment: This is the menu:

<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'main', 'container' => 'nav' )); ?>

How am I supposed to put a <li> inside it?

Comment: It's calling a function with an array of the menu already. So why not edit the array?

Comment: I am not a good programmer, can you tell me a concrete example of how to do that?

Comment: You can do a multi search file for the menu container or items.. Like for example you can use Text Wrangler to search your theme folder for it!